# ASP.NET MVC Runtime error when referenced assembly extension is .exe, no error when assembly renamed to .dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a winforms project that compiles to an executable. (Project.exe)
This project is referenced in a ASP.NET MVC application. The MVC app compiles fine, and puts 'Project.exe' in the bin folder.

On accessing the ASP.NET, a server error is generated:

> Server error in / Application
>
> The type 'X' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You
> must add a reference to assembly 'xxxx, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

```
> Line 10: <div class="container">
> Line 11:     @if (Model.X == null)
> Line 12:     {
```

However, when I rename 'Project.exe' to 'Project.dll', the page runs fine.

- Both projects target .NET 4.5.
- In visual studio and intellisense all is fine.
- There is no .exe.config file
- I have cleaned and reopened the solution. I can consistently produce/reproduce the error based on the file name (exe/dll)

What is going on?

Comment: *Don't* use an `.exe`. Put common code in a separate library. As for what's going on, check your `web.config`, that's what contains the references that can be used by a web application, types used in the web.config itself etc. . You'll see that the assemblies and types are referenced using either full or partial names *without* an extension. The default expectation is that assemblies are dlls, not exes. Some may have a `HintPath` that contains a full path to a dll.

Comment: That's a problem with the application, not a bug with ASP.NET or .NET in general